# Flutter Signalr_core longpolling connection get closing automatically?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, signalrcore

TransportType websockets is not working on Flutter web so i am using longpolling for web,but its  connection gets closing automatically ,how to stop closing connection?

```
HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(url, HttpConnectionOptions(client: httpClient,
    accessTokenFactory: getToken, transport: kIsWeb ? HttpTransportType.longPolling : HttpTransportType.webSockets))
    .build();
```